# Sharepoint deployment packaging (simplest!)

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for a simplest and effective method of sharepoint deployment? Supposedly, you've a package and you deploy no need to separately move the dependencies. There is a tool [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/12/introducing-sharepoint-content.html) but I'm unlucky to get any help from it. It successfully creates a export package but when I import the package on a different machine it doesn't work. I need to deploy a package remotely on a different machine. The utility looks the easiest way of deploy sharepoint package but for me it always end up with an error log:

```
[1/25/2010 5:31:59 PM]: Start Time: 1/25/2010 5:31:59 PM.
[1/25/2010 5:31:59 PM]: Progress: Initializing Import.
[1/25/2010 5:32:10 PM]: FatalError: Could not find WebTemplate JRIM#75805 with LCID 1033.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.VerifyWebTemplate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.Validate(SPRequirementObject reqObj)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportRequirementsManager.DeserializeAndValidate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.VerifyRequirements()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[1/25/2010 5:32:15 PM]: Progress: Import Completed.
[1/25/2010 5:32:15 PM]: Finish Time: 1/25/2010 5:32:15 PM.
[1/25/2010 5:32:15 PM]: Completed with 0 warnings.
[1/25/2010 5:32:15 PM]: Completed with 1 errors.
```

Do you have any idea what is it?

What can be the easiest way to deploy a sharepoint site to another farm? Is there any other tool like SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard? I'm emphasize on easiest because of separate deployment mechanism of web parts which is a awful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the content deployment wizard (nor do you need an expensive tool for this ;), your new server is missing that template: JRIM#75805

You should compare your old and new server for installed add-ons, templates, features, etc. because they will all have to be present on the new server.

Comment: shouldn't it copy all the dependencies? I've exported the site with all dependencies included. Don't it include the template?

Comment: No, these things are on disk. The content deployment wizard only copies 'content', e.g. items in the content database. Including dependancies only works for page layouts, content types etc. within the content database as well.